# How to generate a file xml since several tables from mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I want to generate xml file from several tables in a MySQL database using PHP.

```
$query = "
SELECT
  t.value,
  d.value,
  ty.value, 
  p.id,
  p.ref,
  p.is_renting,
  p.price,
  p.adress,
  p.living_space,
  p.rooms
FROM
  jos_jea_properties p
INNER JOIN
   jos_jea_towns t
ON
  t.id = d.town_id 
INNER JOIN
  jos_jea_departments d 
ON
  d.id = p.department_id 
INNER JOIN
  jos_jea_types ty 
ON
  ty.id = p.type_id";



$result = mysql_query ($query, $link) or die("Could not complete database query");
```

But, it show me Could not complete database query, have you any idea?

Comment: make sure that your query is actually running in somethink like phpmyadmin

Comment: yes, I run my query in server and I want to generate xml fil from database joomla, I want to know if there is something false in the query??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something wrong in your query. Use `mysql_error()` to get the message returned by MySQL.

```
$result = mysql_query ($query, $link) or die("Could not complete database query: ".mysql_error()));
```

However, your query gets a lot of fields named `value`. Use aliases instead, otherwise they're getting replaced

```
    $query = "SELECT t.value t_value, d.value d_value, ty.value ty_value, 
     p.id, p.ref, p.is_renting, p.price, p.adress, 
     p.living_space, p.rooms FROM jos_jea_properties 
     p INNER JOIN jos_jea_towns t ON t.id = d.town_id 
     INNER JOIN jos_jea_departments d ON d.id = p.department_id 
     INNER JOIN jos_jea_types ty ON ty.id = p.type_id";
```

Comment: If it helped you, please tick my answer on the left

Comment: but, I have just a problem now the row of table have the same name, so when I want to show the content of them, I try this code $_xml .="<type>" . $row[ty.value] . "</type>\n";  
$_xml .="<departement>" . $row[d.value] . "</departement>\n"; 
$_xml .="<town>" . $row[t.value]. "</town>\n";  but no results

Comment: the problem is in this $row[ty.value]

Comment: you have to create aliases of them

Comment: I don't inderstand what you means by aliases, can you explain more please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you an idea about a code php How to generate a file xml for image since mysql database using php?